# SQL merging rows differing by 1 parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, so I'm woking on a database, where I have basically a list of ownerships. And sometimes I receive almost duplicate rows, differing only in the amount of the property. I'd like to merge them into one, setting the amount as the sum of the two. Example:

```
Name  Surname Amount
Ann   Evans   4
Ann   Evans   7
```

And I'd like to have just:

```
Ann   Evans   11
```

How do I merge two rows having a common tuple?

Comment: You have an ID column in there, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function along with [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Surname, 
       SUM(Amount) AS total_amount
  FROM tbl 
GROUP BY 
       Name, 
       Surname;
```

UPD.
**Michał Szydłowski**: Okay, but I don't want to select, I want to run an update query, that will permanently modify the table.

The best option I see here, is to use [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html):

```
CREATE TABLE temp_tbl LIKE tbl;

INSERT INTO temp_tbl (Name, Surname, Amount)
SELECT Name, 
       Surname, 
       SUM(Amount) 
  FROM tbl 
GROUP BY 
       Name, 
       Surname;

TRUNCATE tbl;

INSERT INTO tbl (Name, Surname, Amount)
SELECT Name, 
       Surname, 
       Amount
  FROM temp_tbl;
```

Comment: Okay, but I don't want to select, I want to run an update query, that will permanently modify the table.

Comment: nope, I will have to do it another way, this is not working, maybe it is right, but far too complcated. I'll figure it out, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregate function [SUM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) with `GROUP BY` clause, group by the number of columns you want along with result

```
select Name,Surname,sum(Amount) as Amount from table group by Name,Surname
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, SurName, SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount FROM myTable GROUP BY Name, SurName
```

Hope this help.